# Is this solution correct? Prove whether $f(n)$ is $O$, $o$, $\Omega$, $\omega$ or $\Theta$ of $g(n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

$f(n) = n + (\log n)^{2}$, $g(n) = n + \log(n^{2})$.

log is assumed to be base 2

So I differentiated each of the functions

$f(n)' = 1 + 2(\log n)$

$g(n)' = 1 + (2/n\ln(2))$

and then finding the limit of $f(n)' / g(n)'$ as $n$ approaches infinity. Which the denominator approaches 1, while the numerator approaches infinity. Thus, $f(n) = \omega g(n)$?

Is this correct? I'm pretty new so if you could guide me I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You should check your derivatives.

Comment: I checked them and got the same answer, I might be doing it wrong though. So for f(n) both 1 and $(logn)^{2}$ followed the power rule, so that one seems correct. For g(n) I changed $log(n^{2})$ into $2log(n)$ before differentiating. The n in g(n) becomes 1, and the log(n) becomes $1/nln(2)$ and multiplied by 2 at the end since that is a constant. I don't see my mistake, I am pretty new though so I have probably made an error. Could you point it out?

Comment: The derivative of $(\log n)^2$ is $2\log n$ times the derivative of $\log n$.

Comment: Oh can you not use the power rule on (log n)^2? I will rework and edit!

Comment: @FabioSomenzi So the numerator and denominator are equivalent thus f(n)/g(n) approaches 1 and f(n) = Θ g(n)? Is this correct? Also what was the law or rule used to differentiate (log n)^2?

Comment: The rule used to differentiate $(\log n)^2$ is the *chain rule*.  Both functions are $\Theta(n)$.  As you proceed in your study of asymptotics, you'll learn that $n$ dominates the logarithmic terms.